# Stored procedure to get all sub folder and files

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, recursion, parent-child

I have two tables in SQL Server database, `Folder` and `File`.

[image]

[image]

I need a stored procedure that returns me all files and folders within a folder.

Example:

```
 exec GetFileAndFolders @FolderID

 Declare @FolderID uniqueidentifier
 set @FolderID = 'b575050d-374b-e611-9d2c-000c29e7670f'

 ;WITH hierarchy_cte (ID, Name, ParentID) as
 (
     SELECT 
         e.folderId, e.name, e.parentId
     FROM 
         folder as e
     WHERE
         e.folderId = @FolderID

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         e.folderId, e.name, e.parentId
     FROM 
         folder as e
     INNER JOIN 
         hierarchy_cte as h ON h.ParentID = e.folderId
)
SELECT ID FROM hierarchy_cte
```

Comment: Do you have any SQL to show what you have tried and why it is not working? There is also a large amount of help in the internet if you search for it; try Google with "sql recursive query"

Comment: I have a CTE with which I am finding all childs of a folder table but I want to do a join on file table as well so that I get all files and folders within a folder.

Comment: Please add the code you have to the question.

Comment: `FolderId` would be more proper name for `File.ParentId` column!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to approach the problem would be to put all objects (files and folders) in a single table; with an attribute to denote what is a folder. This is how file systems in Windows, Linux, Mac etc. deal with the problem.

Then your existing code would locate all files and folders, with an additional attribute (column) to denote what is a folder.